# How to split a string for regex containing lookbehind and lookahead

Tags: java, regex

I want to split the following string:

```
"VALUE:VALUE,VALUE:[VALUE1,VALUE2,VALUE3],VALUE:VALUE"
```

into

```
"VALUE:VALUE"
"VALUE:[VALUE1,VALUE2,VALUE3]"
"VALUE:VALUE"
```

I expected:

```
String[] elements = text.split("(?<!\\[),|,(?!\\])");
```

to get me part way there as I thought this meant that it wouldn't match a comma if it had a bracket before or after it but this returns:

```
"VALUE:VALUE"
"VALUE:[VALUE1"
"VALUE2"
"VALUE3]"
"VALUE:VALUE"
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: What if your value is "VALUE:[VALUE1,[VALUE2,VALUE3]],VALUE:VALUE" ?

Comment: This looks awfully much like JSON - use a JSON parser. Otherwise write your own little recursive-descent parser. It's not very hard. Regular expressions are only meant for simple grammars, not for anything that can contain recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have any possibility of nesting, try this regex:

```
String[] elements = text.split(",(?![^\\[]*\\])");
```

This matches a comma which is not followed by a `]` without any `[` before it.

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/dIN3Ae)

Comment: @mikea You're welcome! Oh, I also forgot to mention, this also ignores the possibility of escaped square brackets. If you have them, let me know. That regex is only a little more complicated.

Comment: Good point escaped ] of the form \] "\\]" would be very useful

Comment: @mikea Okay, just use this regex if you have escaped `]` then: `,(?!(?:[^[\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\])` (there are a lot of backslashes in Java's regex, phew).